# Visual Studio LESS: Compile main file upon save of imported file

Tags: visual-studio, less, web-essentials

I have this less structure:

- parent.less

  - child1.less
  - child2.less

Is it possible to compile parent.less any time child1 or child2 are saved? I would prefer not to have to build the project for LESS compilation to occur. At the moment I have to trigger a save from parent.less.

I'm using the latest Web Essentials with LESS support, is it possible to do what I want with this?

Many thanks

Comment: Anyone? Would be nice to know... :)

Answer (score 4):

According to "SLaks" comment on the [Uservoice request for this feature](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/4025999-recompile-all-less-files-in-the-project-right-afte). "Press Alt+Shift+Y (Build, Web Essentials, Recompile all LESS Files) to do this without rebuilding."

I agree, it would be a great feature for it to do it automatically without the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick comment in case anyone else stumbles across this while searching, this has been added to WE2013, but if you are still in VS2012 and using WE2012, this still doesn't work, and it doesn't sound like it will be added to 2012.